# Summing Two Columns with a Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a bit of issue trying to sum two column together with a left join - running in to grouping problems.

An example of the issue is below:

Table One: [Order]

```
ID  CustomerID      
1   512         
2   317         
3   562
```

Table Two: [OrderEntry]

```
OrderID     Type    ID  QuantitySold    QuantityReturned
1           A       1   1               0
1           A       2   3               0
1           A       3   1               1
2           A       4   1               1
3           B       5   2               0
```

What I'm trying to display:

```
CustomerID  ID  Sold - Returned     
512         1   1       
512         1   3       
512         1   0       
317         2   0
```

Where [OrderEntry].Type = 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very basic SQL:

```
SELECT
    ord.CustomerID
  , ord.ID
  , orden.QuantitySold - orden.QuantityReturned AS [Sold - Returned]
FROM Order ord
LEFT JOIN OrderEntry orden 
  ON ord.ID = orden.ID
WHERE orden.Type = 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly it. For some reason I had it stuck in my head that this was a SUM.

Comment: If you'd like to group it by customer and/or order id then you would use a sum to get one row for each group.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can use any join as you are using and use concat function on two of your column like this

```
select concat(OrderEntry.QuantitySold, OrderEntry.QuantityReturned) AS newcolumn_name
```

Comment: This is a string concatenation and has nothing to do with arithmetical operations between two columns.